# How to launch Dead Space 2 into the main-menu (skip intro etc)

Tags: dead-space-2

Launching Dead Space 2 from the Origin launcher takes way too long. First, I get to see the EA and Viceral Games and Dead Space 2 Logo. Then I get asked to login with my EA-Account, which to click "Back" then "Okay" then I finally get to the main menu.

I've bought the game with the latest Humble Origin Bundle 2.

I've tried to add `+com_skipIntroVideo 1` on the command-line argument. But it does nothing.

[image: Dead Space 2, command-line argument. Added so there can be no missunderstand how this looks like on my PC]

I've added a short-cut of my exe-file on my desktop and I'd like to get to the main-menu with the fewest clicks and keyboard taps as possible. Is there a movie-file I can delete? A command-line option I couldn't find with google? How can I speed up the start-up process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to skip the EA movie logo intro

The movie is stored as in the `Trio_FrontEnd.vp6`  file, in your `<Origin-installatioan-path>\Dead Space 2\movies\<lanugage>\`-folder. Rename the file to `Trio_FrontEnd.vp6` to e.g. `Trio_FrontEnd.vp6.old` so the game can't load it anymore.

#### If you don't know what your origin installation path is

Open origin and open the first menu `Origin`, then select `Application Settings` [image: Application Settings]

There, select the lowest entry `Advanced`, the upper path is where your Origin games are installed. In my case this is `D:\Origin Games` [image: origin games installation path]

### How to skip the EA-Account login

I'm not 100% sure how I did it. I've found out that the origin account is essentially the ea account the game is bugging me to login.

I've tried to login with my origin credentials. This didn't work. Creating a new account with the mail-address I've already used for origin the system said I couldn't create a new one with that a login-name. Reseting the password, didn't do anything.

I think, while I tried to create a new EA account and finally backing out of it. I was shown a dialog, the option "Don't bother me again". I clicked it and I didn't get bugged again to login while starting DP2.